# vb6: looking for activeX audio component (load/play/display wav)

Tags: vb6, audio, components, wav

i'm looking for an activeX component which allows loading .wav files, displaying + playing it - and also is capable of displaying/setting the current playing position.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either Windows Media Player right of the box (choose Components "Windows Media Player").  It can be used with or without the controls (select Custom from the properties menu to turn off the controls) and supports events for everything you need.  It plays wav files, mp3 files, and on Windows 7 and newer operating systems AAC's out of the box (basically anything windows media player supports).  If this doesn't float your boat, installing [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) gives you the VLC activex control, however redistributing it might have some issues.